# Call a python package from powershell script

Tags: powershell, python

I have a conda environment activated in the powershell command prompt.
I have a python package that has been installed with pip:

```
pip install -e .
```

which installs my package with an entry point `simulate`. It works fine when called from the powershell command prompt:

```
simulate "abcd"
```

When I try to call it from within a powershell script it cannot be found.

```
powershell.exe .\run.ps1
```

returns:

```
simulate : The term 'simulate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At C:\path\to\script\run.ps1:1 char:1
+ simulate "abcd"
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nwsetup:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: I assume simulate is an executable connected to Python. So have you tried providing a full path to the executable?

Comment: That seems to have solved that issue, thanks. Out of interest, why can't the script "see" the same executable as the command prompt?

Comment: You should submit a detailed answer explaining what exactly resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `simulate "abcd"` by `C:\path\to\script\simulate.exe "abcd"` inside the poweshell script resolved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Start-Process` and its `-ArgumentList` option to execute the python command (or script) passing it the argument value the actual python command (or script) expects. Set the `-FilePath` parameter to be the full path to the `python.exe` file on Windows.

### PowerShell

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Python\python.exe" -ArgumentList 'simulate "abcd"';
```

or call a python script

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Python\python.exe" -ArgumentList '"c:\scripts\simulate.py" "abcd"';
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Start-process](https://ss64.com/ps/start-process.html)